# Android 4.0 (API 15) uses invalid resources qualifiers

Tags: android, android-resources

Here I have two devices:

1. 960x540   device - normal hdpi   -> 640dp x 360dp
2. 1920x1080 device - normal xxhdpi -> 640dp x 360dp

On android 4.1+ resources qualifiers are:

1. values-sw360dp-hdpi
2. values-sw360dp-xxhdpi

And it all works flawlessly.

But on API 15 by tests application gets resources from folder with highest dpi available, but not best match, so first device receives resources from full hd device.

Is any way, additional param to fix this bug?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? I'm having an issue with the values maps as well. When using an emulator I noticed that the Samsung Galaxy s2(hdpi - 800x480) device uses the same values map as the HTC One (xhdpi - 1920x1080) device. So they both dig in values-sw320dp for example, or they ignore the map at all and look at the default 'values' directory.

Comment: Some workaround, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work around: mark resources with swXXX as swXXX-v16 and provide resources like in android 2.x e.g. drawable-normal-hdpi this is the only way i found to fix this behavior.